# How to use ProgressDialog with webview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

Now im trying to show a page in webview, it takes some time to load, meanwhile i want to show a progressDialog. The best i could do was the code below, but the problem is that im doing it in onCreateView, so the progressDiealog only shows until the view is created, which is not what i want. I know that i have to use it in onActivityCreated , but im not sure how to do that , thanks all in advance

```
public class someFragment extends SherlockFragment {
Context context;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
    {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, group, false);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),  "", "Loading", true);

    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewsome);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });

    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setInitialScale(25);

    myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.test.com/test-0.jpg");

    return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `SomeFragment`:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //remove your progressdialog here
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        //show your progressdialog here
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

}
```

then:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, in `onCreateView` start a `AsyncTask` with a `progressDialog` in it. In `onPageFinished`(after web page completely loaded) of `webView`, cancel that task. Hope its useful.